# Can an electron change direction in a conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism

Can an electron change direction in a conductor? Or is it restricted to do so? Why can't it change direction do to the atoms of the conductor itself?

Why if the change in the electron's direction change/effect the magnitude of the Lorentz force? In fact, does it? I assume so due to the formula: $ F$ = $q$$[$ $E$ + $v\times$ $B$$]$ the velocity would cause of effect, but why would the change in direction change the velocity?

Here is a example of an electron beam bing able to curve:

[image]

Comment: Do you think electron can't change direction? If you can explain, the question would be much useful to discuss.

Comment: Electrons do not flow in a straight line. What do you think resistance is caused by?

Comment: Question not clear.

Comment: 1) Can the direction of an electron change in a free moving conductor? -- 2) If an electron changes its direction in a conductors, how does it change $v$ in the Lorentz force? -- 3) Would the force decrease due tom that change in $v$?

Comment: "free moving conductor" ? Is your conductor moving? Are you asking the effect of reversal of velocity of single electron on the lorentz force summed over the entire conductor?

Comment: No, its not moving but able to move when placed in the magnetic field and current flows within it. I'm not sure what you mean by the second part... but I wondering about the over-all change in the electrons direction.

Answer (score 1):

The picture in your question shows electrons in a vaccum being deflected by the Lorentz force. Exactly the same effect happens in conductors when the electrons making up a current are deflected by a magnetic field, and this is called the [Hall effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect).

It's not a bad approximation to consider the electrons in a metal as forming a gas, and this is known as the [free electron gas model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_electron_gas). The electrons are free to move in any direction just as they would be in a gas.

Comment: John, the Hall effect is when the conductor is mechanically fixed isn't it? I mean lets assume the case of a conductor that can move freely in a magnetic field, the wire itself moves not the electron direction?

Comment: @Key: Yes, when measuring the Hall effect the conductor is fixed. This seemes to me the closest analogy to your picture - electrons moving sideways in a fixed conductor. It shows that electrons aren't restricted to moving in the direction the current is flowing.

Comment: And the case of the moving wire, those electrons do not change direction? They whole wire moves? So... any conductor(size/shape) that can move in that case I stated above, the conductor itself moves, however, the electron's in that conductor does not change direction and the Lorentz force is not changed?

Comment: Side question -- the Lorentz force can theoretically be applied to any kind of moveable conductor(regardless of shape/size)that has large or small currents? I don't know if there is a limitation of the Lorentz force on any scale of a system? Large or small...